# java creating a class method that searches an array for word length

Tags: java, arrays

so i've already made a class method that searches for a specific word, but (like most times i find myself on here!) i've had a brain malfunction and can't figure out how to modify it to do what i need. here's what i've got so far:

```
private static int findFourLetterWord(String[] strings, String key) {
   for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
      if (strings[i].equals(key))
      return i;
   return -1;
}
```

so this searches an array for 'key' and returns with it's position if it is found. what i'm trying to get it to do is search an array of strings for the first 4 letter word it encounters and return with that word. i would change the first return to be `System.out.println(strings[i]);` i believe, but i'm not sure how to make it search for the first 4 letter word it finds. tried using a bunch of convoluted substrings but that didn't work. any advice or guidance would be great. thank you in advance.

Comment: String has a length() method. And you're confusing "returning a word" with "printing a word on the screen", which are very different.

Comment: You can simply use `strings[i].subString(0,4).equals(key)`. I don't believe that you really don't know about `length()` method

Comment: Your question is a little misleading. Are you searching the index of the first word with 4 characters or searching for the index of the first word whose 4 first characters match a certain string? You mention `length` first and `substrings` later.

Comment: right sorry, let's see if i can clarify. the purpose is to search the array for the first word that has only 4 characters and to return what that word is. right now in my code, it's returning the place in the array, i need it to return the actual word.

Comment: Can't help notice your method name starts with an upper case. Just have a quick read of the naming conventions in Java http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I understanding your question right?

```
private static String findFourLetterWord(String[] strings) {
   for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
      if (strings[i].length()==4)
          return strings[i];
   return null;
}
```

Comment: yes but instead of return i it would need to return the string itself.

Comment: quick question, trying to compile this and getting errors. i went and tried to tweak things and ran into more problems. since all i'm doing is creating a class method is there some other requirements to compile? tried adding in public static void main among other things to no avail, suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Your current method is close; you just need to change the condition in the for-loop to check for a length of 4 using [`String#length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) rather than equality to a key argument.

```
private static String findFourLetterWord(String[] strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        if (str.length() == 4) {
            return str;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Never forget to consult the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html) when you find yourself unsure of what methods are available for your convenience.

Comment: It isn't return i or -1 but i think you need to return the String from strings[i]

Comment: @RafaelCelerier Very good catch, I missed that in the question earlier.  Edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: i'm not understanding the for (String str : strings) will that search the entire array?

Comment: That's a [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop, also known as the enhanced for loop in Java.  It iterates through every value in an array/collection.  I had a standard for loop earlier in the code but changed it, since the enhanced one works just as well in this situation (and looks nicer in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` function to get the first 4 character of the key and string as below:

```
 private static int FindFourLetterWord(String[] strings, String key) {
   //Assuming key length is 4 or more
   String keyWithFourChars = key.substring(0,4); 

   for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
     if(strings[i].length() > 3){
        if (strings[i].substring(0,4).eqauls(keyWithFourChars)){
         return i;
        }
      }
    }
    return -1;
 }
```

If you want to just look for 4 chars string, then simply check the length as below:
In this case, you don't need to pass `key` as parameter.

```
 private static int FindFourLetterWord(String[] strings) {
   for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
       if(strings[i].length() == 4){
         return i;
       }
    }
    return -1;
 }
```

Comment: The question isn't to find a substring of a key, it's to find a string with a length of 4.  From the question: *"search an array of strings for the first 4 letter word it encounters and return with that word"*.

Comment: @Vulcan: I read this as `first 4 letter word`, here the 4 letters are of from key to match. Isn't that?

Comment: I read it as "first 4 letter word" as well, but I understand the question as simply the first 4 letter word, unrelated to keys.  The example code is very misleading and it's an overall confusing question, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Vulcan: Added another section to manage if OP is looking for 4 letters word. I am still not sure about the real requirement.